# Is this an error in Spring-Kafka documentation about BatchErrorHandler?

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-kafka

I'm reading [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/#annotation-error-handling) about error handling in kafka batch consuming.

The doc suggests to set a custom error handler in this way:

```
@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
        kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    ...
    factory.getContainerProperties().setBatchErrorHandler(myBatchErrorHandler);
    ...
    return factory;
}
```

but from 2.2.x the `setBatchErrorHandler` is not applicable to `ContainerProperties`.

I tried to call it directly from the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` and I don't have any compilation issues: is this the right way? Is this an error in documentation?

Thanks a lot. Hope this help the Spring Community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks; it's a documentation bug; fixed; it was moved from the properties to the factory some time ago.